# GROUP BY on a FROM SUBQUERY takes too long

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

This was supposed to be a fairly easy query but somehow i'm stuck at it. I have a history table with two column, (string)barcode_member and (timestamo)borrow_date.

I want to get the five member that borrows the most in a month so i wrote this query

```
select barcode_member, count(barcode_member) as total from history 
where DATE(borrow_date) BETWEEN '2022-07-1' AND '2022-07-31' 
group by barcode_member order by total desc
```

which takes 74 seconds so i tried exporting the data retrieved from the where clause (3805 rows) and queried the count-group by on it where it only took 0.0071 seconds. Based on that logic, i wrote the code below to optimize the query time

```
select barcode_member, count(barcode_member) as total 
from (select barcode_member from history where DATE(borrow_date) BETWEEN '2022-07-1' AND '2022-07-31') as tabel 
group by barcode_member order by total desc
```

but the load time is still the same as the first code. Can anyone explain why this happen and give some advice on optimizing the query?

Comment: The where clause is executed before the group by, so you cannot gain much by moving the where clause into a subquery. Add a compound index on borrow_date and barcode_member columns and rewrite your where condition that it can use the index using >= and <=.